# Is it possible in vb6 to get the file name of a dll from within then dll itself?

Tags: vb6

is it possible in vb6 to get the file name of a .dll from within then dll itself ?
Bizarre I know, but I’m in a situation where I have an executable that loads a dll at runtime, each dll has its version in the file name so X_V904.dll, X_V905.dll, etc.
I need to match the loaded dll file name to a value in the a db. I can’t pass the file name to the dll I can only try and get I from code within the dll itself.

Ive looked everywhere and can’t find any way of doing it, is this not possible or has anyone tried to do anything like this before ?

Comment: Do you have the dll source and can you modify them to add a new property?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the application object to get the file name.  Try this:

```
App.EXEName
```